# passing dropdown selected value to URL in javascript for an anchor tag opening window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down which has months as options.

Then I have an anchor tag which opens a window on click. I'm trying to pass the value of the drop down selected to the URL so that after opening the window I will retrieve it using post.

Here's the drop down.

```
<select name="datestart" id="datestart" class="form-control" style="width:500px;">
          <option value="">--Select Month--</option>
          <option value="01">January</option>
          <option value="02">February</option>
          <option value="03">March</option>
          <option value="04">April</option>
          <option value="05">May</option>
          <option value="06">June</option>
          <option value="07">July</option>
          <option value="08">August</option>
          <option value="09">September</option>
          <option value="10">October</option>
          <option value="11">November</option>
          <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
```

Now here's the anchor tag

```
<a href="#" id="detailswindow" onclick="window.open('pages/modals.php','mywindow','width=1100,height=500');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Details</a>
```

This is the javascript I have so far but still not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var datestart = document.getElementById("datestart");
     var link = document.getElementById("detailswindow");
     if(datestart.value == "01")
       {
          link.href = "pages/modals?mode=modename&theme=Standard";
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the way you are handling click. Instead of using hard coded `window.open` create a function:

```
function handleClick() {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById('datestart');
    var dropValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;

    window.open('pages/modals.php?param=' + dropValue ,'mywindow','width=1100,height=500')
}
```

And in you will have access to the `param` when loading that page.

```
<a href="#" id="detailswindow" onclick="handleClick()">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Details
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a value then save the month in a string. Then, when the anchor tag is clicked, append the month to the url with a variable name.. something like this

```
$('a#detailswindow').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //stop the page from redirecting
   window.open('pages/modals.php?month=' + $('select#datestart').val(),'mywindow','width=1100,height=500');
});
```

In PHP you can access the variable using

```
$_GET["month"]
```